# c++ checking if braces match

Tags: c++

I've been asked as a bonus programming challenge to see if braces match in a random string or char like this: {1+1} this would return 1, while {1+1}) would return 0.
This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be great? thanks

```
//bonus.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int checkBraces (string s)
{
    //int myLength = s.length();
    std::stack<int> stack;
    char d;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];

        if (c == '(')
        {
            stack.push(c);
        }
        else if (c == '[') 
        {
            stack.push(c);
        }
        else if (c == '{')
        {
            stack.push(c);
        }

        else if (c == ')')
        {
            if (stack.empty())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                d = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
                if (d != '(')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (c == ']')
        {
            if (stack.empty())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                d = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
                if (d != '[')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (c == '}')
        {
            if (stack.empty())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                d = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
                if (d != '{')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (stack.empty()) return true;
    else return false;

}


int main()
{
    cout << "This program checks brace ([{}]) matching in a string." << endl;

    checkBraces ("{1+1}");

}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's actually going on ?

Comment: *doesn't seem to do anything* - could use more info here.

Comment: You've got quite a bit of redundancy. Perhaps you should have a `bool pop_if_possible(std::stack<char>, char)` method so you can write `if (c==')' && !pop_if_possible(stack, '(')) { return false; }`

Comment: I've got the program to working just fine, I'm just not sure how to make it return 1 or 0 if it is matching or not matching using the actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it doesn't seem to do anything

It does do something. It prints `This program checks brace ([{}]) matching in a string.`.

You are calling `checkBraces ("{1+1}")` but you aren't doing anything with the returned value. Since this call can be optimized away, you are in a sense correct that your program doesn't seem to do anything.

So make it do something. Print the string that is to be tested, then print the result of the test. Once you have done that, you should test, and when you're done with that, you should test some more. Don't just test easy cases such as `{i+1}`. Test convoluted cases that should pass, and also test cases that should fail.

Learning how to test and learning how to debug are just as important skills (if not more important skills) as is learning how to write code.

Comment: I can't believe all I had to do was cout << checkBraces (input); My program is working great thanks. I have tested several cases Iw as just using that one as I knew it should return 1.

Answer (score 6):

What makes you think it doesn't do anything? It does. It checks for braces, but you're not doing anything with the return of `checkBraces`, which, btw, should return a `bool`, not an `int`.

Did you perhaps meant something like:

```
if (checkBraces ("{1+1}"))
   cout << "matching";
else
   cout << "not matching";
```

Pro-tip: **learn how to use a debugger**. You should learn how to debug before you start coding anything more than a "hello world".

Comment: `"{ ( } )"` is accounted for: when `'}'` is encountered, the top of stack will be `'('`.

Comment: @MSalters ah, that's true, I missed that.

Comment: okay okay using your IF statement you provided me my program seems to be working pretty well. I just need to be able to prompt the user to enter a string and return 1 or 0. Which I think I can accomplish by making that method a boolean instead of an int?

Comment: @AlanGordon no, to take user input you need `std::cin` (google)

Comment: Re *You should learn how to debug before you start coding anything more than a "hello world"*: +1 for that. +10, or even more, if I could. Sometimes it's too bad we can't "vote early, vote often" here at SO.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to what have already been said, I would say that you could reduce the amount of code. As anyway you put chars into your stack, why not having a `std::stack<char>`?

You could save the braces into another string, to automatically compare it using one of the [std::algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

```
const std::string openingBraces("{[(");
const std::string closingBraces("}])");

if (std::find(openingBraces.begin(), openingBraces.end(), currentChar) != openingBraces.end())
    yourStack.push(currentChar);
else if (std::find(closingBraces.begin(), closingBraces.end(), currentChar) != closingBraces.end())
{
    // check if currentChar is matching the one on top of your stack
}
```

I haven't written everything as it's always better to find answers by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum you should do is to print the outcome of checkBraces.