# A recursive function for brackets analysis

Tags: c++, file-io, recursion

So i need a recursive function which returns true when it finds a matching pair of brackets. What i managed to make is below. The fuction is called from outside when the first bracket is found. It works just fine for a simple example like (TEXT), but i need to modify it so it can work with nested braces. Something like (T(E)XT). And i just can't figure out how to do it. And i'm not very good with recursion in the first place. And i can't use a stack or a queue or anything like that. Can you help me, o wisest stackowerflow?

```
bool Round(ifstream &infile, char s)
{
    bool ret;
    if (s==')') 
    {
        cout<<s;
        return true;
    }
    if (s=='(')
    {
    //I DON'T KNOW WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN HERE
    }
    else 
    {

        cout<<s;
        infile>>s;
        ret=Round(infile,s);
    }
return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output for this function?

Comment: When you find a open brace, do the recursion.

Comment: just call your recursive function again

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760336/c-checking-if-braces-match

Comment: I had an idea that i could use another boolean to call the function in case i found an opening bracket and then conjuncting it with the ret. But it didn't work. Or maybe i wrote it wrong.

Comment: @AndersonGreen This one uses a stack, and i can't use it in this task.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Sample input would be any combination of nested brackets. Like (A((B)C)D). And the output is just true or false, if all the brackets match or not

Comment: @Code-Apprentice when i do that, it only goes until the first closing bracket and returns true. For example if my input is (T(E)XT) it prints only (T(E) and returns true when there is a whole another bracket there.

Comment: @woolywhale Sorry I can't downvote currently. What was your particular question again? Which anomalies did you notice, when you stepped through your program with a debugger, or with a decent test case you've been writing for it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The problem i have is that my function stops on the first closing bracket, and i need it to go until all the matching brackets are found. If i have something like (AAA(BBB)CCC) it only prints (AAA(BBB),returns true and ignores the last closing bracket. And i can't figure out how to make it go until the last one using only recursion.
I'm sorry if i'm annoying you with my dumbass questions. It's just that i don't have anyone to ask and i've been trying to solve this for a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of recursive descent parsing is that you delegate responsibility to functions that each know how to parse their part of the syntax, and they can be nested (ie. call each other, or call themselves).

At any point while scanning, if the next character in the stream is the `FIRST` character of a state(N), then that **predicts** the state(N), so what must you do? match state(N) (parse or consume it).

Not sure why you called your function Round(), I'd call it `match_block()`

Within the match function for that state, scan characters, looking for the `REST` of that state, but also recursively scan for `FIRST` character of any other legal nested states. In your case its simple, you can either expect whitespace, `(` or `)`

So the point of nesting is `FIRST(block)` == `(` and `REST(block)` == `)`, but if we also find `(` within a block, that predicts another, so match it again.

Without writing it for you, I assume you understand recursion is as simple as:

```
void foo() {

    foo();

}
```

Obviously you don't want that, its infinite recursion. But that is the recursive portion. The logic is the part you already know (how to match "brackets")

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I suggest solving the problem for input that **only** contains parentheses. In pseudocode, the solution can look something like this:

if I see an open paren
       consume it and recursively match parens
       if I see a close paren
           return true
       else
           return false

Note that this solution matches the **open** parenthesis first and **then** looks for a matching closing parenthesis. Contrast this with the code you have written. I think this is one reason you are struggling.

Now if you can code this and get it working for output only containing parentheses, see what you can do to consume other characters. Again, you want to keep things simple. For example, try to solve the problem with input characters '(', ')', and ' '. Assume that these are the **only** input characters and test it accordingly.

When you can get it working with spaces and parentheses, it should be an easy step to finally allow any text at all.